# How do I create a current doctype?

Tags: doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
```

I am getting indications that the heading of my webpage  is out of date and may be causing the search engines to ignore it. Can anyone suggest how I can update it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is giving you that indication?

Comment: Articles citing the preference for xml language by the search engines and a marked drop in my site traffic. Also in the page source that heading now comes up in red lettering.

Comment: It's unlikely that search engines care. What they need to do is to provide the best page results that they can, and that depends on the content, not on esoteric flags in the markup. But, as the answers to most of the doctype tagged questions will tell you, `<!DOCTYPE html>` is your friend.